# Can not remove the printed word "Array"

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieved data from MySQL but the result is like this: http://sparrow.site90.net/select.php

It shows the word `(Array)` before the retrieved information. I tried so hard to remove this word from the table but I could not.

Here is my code. What can I do about it?

```
echo "<td>" . $array = unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']);
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item, ", ";
}
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: What does `$array` contain if you echo it?

Comment: echo within loop is not good idea in this case, better is to write like, `$output = "<td>" .unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']) ;
        foreach($array as $item) {
            $output .= $item,", ";
        }              $output .=  "</td>"; echo $output;`

Comment: please add your table data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row concatenates the array's textual representation (which, in PHP, is `"Array"`) and the starting element `<td>`. Here's what you should do:

```
$array = unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']);
echo "<td>";
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item, ", ";
}
echo "</td>";
```

Answer (score 8):

You are concatenating and echoing your array:

```
echo "<td>" .  $array= unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']) ;
```

should be:

```
$array = unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']);
echo "<td>";
```

Comment: I tried that before but all I get is syntax error

look I did what you just said

$array= unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']) ;
 echo "<td>" .  
   foreach($array as $item) {
   echo $item,", ";
          }    "</td>";

Comment: @Sparrow Don't add the `foreach` on the same line as the `echo` statement and don't contactenate it (the dot) to the string. Keep it the way it was and just change the first line.

Answer (score 0):

A better code will be something like this:

```
$array = unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']);
echo "<td>".implode(",",$array)."</td>";
```

In the snippet above, the implode method will neatly insert commas in between the array values and echo a concatenated string of Favorite courses separated by comma.

Read the documentation here: [PHP - implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: `$output = "<td>"; $array = unserialize($row['Favorite_courses']) ; foreach($array as $item) { $output .= $item,", "; } $output .= "</td>"; $pos=strripos($output,","); $len = strlen($output)-$pos; $output = substr($output,0,$len); echo $output;`  this will remove last ","  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php